# How to dismiss the Progress Bar?

Tags: android

I'm new to android now I'm developing an application where a file is downloaded.
I want to show a progressbar while the file is being download.i don't know where to check the condition for showing the Progress Bar and also i don't know how to dismiss the Progress Bar.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `setVisibility` function and use  `View.GONE`

```
if(progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
{
   progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of people have confusion on ProgressBar and ProgressDialog.

ProgressBar is a view in layout and ProgressDialog is class.

To enable, disable, dismiss progressbar we need to use:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and to dismiss progressdialog we need to write:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score -1):

That's done with the help of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (an intelligent backround thread) and [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

When the AsyncTask starts we raise a progressdialog with indeterminate state, once the task is finished we dismiss the dialog.

**Example code**
What the adapter does in this example is not important, more important to understand that you need to use AsyncTask to display a dialog for the progress.

```
private class PrepareAdapter1 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ContactsListCursorAdapter > {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(viewContacts.this);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait_while_loading));
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    @Override
    protected ContactsListCursorAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {
        cur1 = objItem.getContacts();
        startManagingCursor(cur1);

        adapter1 = new ContactsListCursorAdapter (viewContacts.this,
                R.layout.contact_for_listitem, cur1, new String[] {}, new int[] {});

        return adapter1;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ContactsListCursorAdapter result) {
        list.setAdapter(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was showing progress bar inside onProgressUpdate, and it wouldn't dismiss on onPostExecute. Then I displayed it on onPreExecute and it works just perfect. +1

Comment: OP's question is on ProgressBar not ProgressDialog. So Any way to dismiss ProgressBar?